# How to get nested keys for typescript object and array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, recursion, ecmascript-6

For a form generator I am trying to get typesafety for a nested object and array of objects. I would like for the name property to have as value the key of the object that it belongs to.

So in the example below, name.name has to have as value "name".

For the array, the names of the objects have to be of the types nested within choices So an object with name: "parentOption" and a option with name: "code"

For the nested object it has to nest all the way untill the last property and I want the object properties and the name to be typed. What I mean by this is that,

Position > Location > x | y | z are the only names allowed to be supplied.

I hope this makes a bit sense. With the Keyof T, I am only able to type the first levels of the form object, so question, choices, and position are typed. However for the deeper levels, I have to use recursion and I have had no success so far, thanks!

```js
type FormSchema = {
  name: string
  choices: { choice: string }[]
  position: { location: { x: number, y: number, z: number } }
}

type TextField = {
  name: string
  label: string
}

const form = {
  name: {
    name: "name", // name must be name
    label: "Question A"
  },
  choices: [
    {
      name: "choice", //name must be choice
      label: "Choice"
    }
  ],
  position: { //this has to be position
    location: { //this has to be location
      x: {name: "x", label: "X"}, //name must be x
      y: {name: "y", label: "Y"}, //name must be y
      z: {name: "z", label: "Z"}, //name must be z
    },
  }
}
```

[image]
I added an image to make it a bit more clear of what I want. All properties connected by the lines to the type should be automatically typed. However, it must be dynamic so that any type used is automatically typed.

Comment: Looks more like  a mapper than a type

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you're trying to do, but form seems to be of type

```
type FormSchema = {
  question: { id: 'question'; label: string };
  choices: { id: 'choice'; label: string }[];
  position: { location: { x: number, y: number, z: number } } ;
}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: `location` is different

Comment: @Jérémy Rippert

I added an image at the top hope it makes it more clear. FormSchema was just an example, the keys can be any dynamic string. So basically, I would like to have a FormSchema type which excepts a generic type T. And all keys of T should be typed in a tree structured manner. – 

Thanks!

Comment: Okay. May I ask why you want to have (for instance with `question`) `question: { id: 'question', label: 'Question }` ? Since `question.id` simply equals `question`, I don't see the added value of the `id` property, it seems that you could simply do `question: 'Question'` @Re-Angelo

Comment: @JérémyRippert Uhm the reason was that eventually the id/name property gets spread into a react component. So <Input id={id} name={name} label={label}/>

Comment: @Re-Angelo even with this approach you could use the key as the variable, so if you had `const form = { question1: 'Question 1', question2: 'Question 2' }`, you could iterate on `Object.keys(form)` (which results in `['question1', 'question2']`) like this: `Object.keys(form).map(key => <input id={key} name={key} label={form[key]} />`